# What is the proper way to use glmnet with caret?

Tags: r, r-caret, glm, glmnet

I was reading the glmnet documentation and I found this:

> Note also that the results of cv.glmnet are random, since the folds
>   are selected at random. Users can reduce this randomness by running
>   cv.glmnet many times, and averaging the error curves.

The following code uses caret with a repeated cv.

```
library(caret)

ctrl <- trainControl(verboseIter = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, 
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, method = "repeatedcv", 
                     repeats = 10) 

fit <- train(x, y, method = "glmnet", metric = "ROC", trControl = ctrl)
```

Is that the best way to run glmnet with cross validation through caret?, or is it better to run glmnet directly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define *best way*. Do you want to use

- A regularized regression alone on a dataset for feature selection? (in which case, use glmnet--Max Kuhn has implied that you may be better off using models with in-built CV features as they would have been optimized for both predictor selection and minimizing error). See below.

  > "In many cases, using these models with built-in feature selection will be more efficient than algorithms where the search routine for
  >   the right predictors is external to the model. Built-in feature
  >   selection typically couples the predictor search algorithm with the
  >   parameter estimation and are usually optimized with a single
  >   objective function (e.g. error rates or likelihood)." (Kuhn, caret
  >   package documentation: [caret feature selection overview](http://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-overview.html))
- Or are you comparing different models, one of which is glmnet? In which case, caret may be a great choice.